# Syntax error for describe addresses using AllocationIds as Filter using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to describe one of the Elastic IPs in my environment but getting below error:

```
>>> ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', 'ap-south-1')
>>> response = client.describe_addresses(
...     Filters=[
...             AllocationIds=['eipalloc-000f89e6a8a331b84','eipalloc-03d4d2f93bdcb134d']
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    AllocationIds=['eipalloc-000f89e6a8a331b84','eipalloc-03d4d2f93bdcb134d']
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The link I'm referring is https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_addresses

Please can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation `Filters` and `AllocationIds` are separate parameters to `describe_addresses()`.

Perhaps what you are looking for is: (with suitable extra fields)

```
response = client.describe_addresses(Filters=[], AllocationIds=['eipalloc-000f89e6a8a331b84','eipalloc-03d4d2f93bdcb134d'])
```

Comment: That's so stupid of me ! Thanks for showing the miss.